# Comparing certain part of date only

Tags: java

I'd like to know if say i have the following arrays

```
A = [JAN-2014, FEB-2014, MARCH-2014]
B = [1-JAN-2014, 13-FEB-2014, 29-MARCH-2014]
C = [2014-Jan, 2014-Feb, 2014-March]
```

Is it possible to compare the dates between the 3 arrays based on the months only without converting the either one of the array's date format to follow the others?

Comment: If they are represented by Java Date objects I would like to believe that they would have a month integer field you could use.

Comment: You really should convert them to proper dates. String hacking *may* somehow be faster, but they are definitely less readable and more error prone.

Comment: Parse the dates and compare it with `java.util.Date` or `java.util.Calendar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use

```java
    public static final SimpleDateFormat SDF_DATE = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd");
    public static final SimpleDateFormat SDF_HOUR = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    public String getDateAddedToString() {
            return DateFormatters.SDF_DATE.format(dateAdded.getTime());
    }
```

..and then..

`"example_string".equals(getDateAddedToString());`

With months use:

`public static final SimpleDateFormat SDF_MONTH = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM")`

Or use `substring` and `regex` of String class.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

```
String aString = "JAN-2014";
SimpleDateFormat aDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mmm-yyyy");
Date aDate = aDateFormat.parse(aString);

String bString = "13-FEB-2014";
SimpleDateFormat bDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mmm-yyyy");
Date bDate = bDateFormat.parse(bString);

String cString = "2014-feb";
SimpleDateFormat cDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mmm");
Date cDate = cDateFormat.parse(cString);

Calendar aCal = Calendar.getInstance();
aCal .setTime(aDate);

Calendar bCal = Calendar.getInstance();
bCal .setTime(bDate);

Calendar cCal = Calendar.getInstance();
cCal .setTime(cDate);

int aMonth = aCal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int bMonth = bCal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int cMonth = cCal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Then you can compare the integer value of the months

Comment: Sorry I have just noticed the issue that you are having with the month format of 'Feb' & 'March' in the same array I will look into this now